# Messenger Send API Error "The parameter "error":{"message":"(#100) For field 'messages': user_id is required"

Tags: node.js, messenger, request-promise, facebook-send-api

I have the problem with Send API. I have tried to use POSTMAN, cURL to post the message to my messenger account. It works correctly with POSTMAN or cURL. However, I have built the Node.js to send the message. The error is " The parameter user_id is required". I have no idea how to fix this. Since in document, there is no user_id field.

```
 const body = {
  "recipient": {
    "id": SOME_PAGE_SCOPE_ID
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "Test Message"
  }
};
request({
   methods: "POST",
          uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/v${GRAPH_API_VERSION}/me/messages`,
          qs: {
            access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
          },
          body: body,
          json: true
        }).then(fulfil => console.log(fulfil)).error(err => console.log(err));
```

LS. GRAPH_VERSION is 2.9
The reference link is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

Comment: this is the error.
“The parameter ”error“:{”message“:”(#100) For field 'messages': user_id is required"

Comment: Are you getting properly the `SOME_PAGE_SCOPE_ID` value?

Comment: OK I fixed bug already. The problem is "methods" should be "method".

Answer (score 0):

You need "**SOME_USER_ID**" instead of "**SOME_PAGE_SCOPE_ID**",

And I think you missed a "**message_type**" parameter in the JSON.